# How to exclude SNAPSHOT or other dependencies from Android Studio Gradle suggestions

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Android Studio prompts to upgrade dependencies when there are newer versions

```
A newer version of xxx.yyy:yyy-lib than 1.0.1 is available: 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

However if you "contaminate" the dependencies with a snapshot, it will still prompt to upgrade.  How can you tell Android Studio to ignore snapshot dependencies, or even a problematic version?

Can Dependency Resolution be used to filter the versions? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html